# How to feed a spider with links crawled within the spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm writing a spider (**CrawlSpider**) for an online store. According to client requisites, I need to write two rules: one for determining which pages have items and other for extracting the items.

I have both rules already working independently:

- if my `start_urls = ["www.example.com/books.php",
  "www.example.com/movies.php"]` and I comment the `Rule` and the code
  of `parse_category`, my `parse_item` will extract every item.
- On the other hand, if `start_urls = "http://www.example.com"` and I
  comment the `Rule`and the code of `parse_item`, `parse_category` will
  return every link in which there a items for extracting, i.e.
  `parse_category` will return `www.example.com/books.php` and
  `www.example.com/movies.php`.

My problem is that I don't know how to merge both modules, so that `start_urls = "http://www.example.com"` and then `parse_category` extracts `www.example.com/books.php` and `www.example.com/movies.php` and feed those links to `parse_item`, where I actually extract the info of each item.

I need to find a way to do it this way instead of just using `start_urls = ["www.example.com/books.php", "www.example.com/movies.php"]` because if in the future a new category is added (e.g. `www.example.com/music.php`), the spider wouldn't be able to automatically detect that new category and should be manually edited. Not a big deal, but the client doesn't want this.

```
class StoreSpider (CrawlSpider):
    name = "storyder"

    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]
    #start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/books.php", "http://www.example.com/movies.php"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='parse_category'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=False, callback="parse_item"),
    )

def parse_category(self, response):
    category = StoreCategory()
    # some code for determining whether the current page is a category, or just another stuff 
    if is a category:
        category['name'] = name
        category['url'] = response.url
    return category

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = StoreItem()
    # some code for extracting the item's data
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `parse_category`, I used `restrict_css` in `LinkExtractor`to get the links I want, and it seems to be feeding the second `Rule` with the extracted links, so my question is answered. It ended up this way:

```
class StoreSpider (CrawlSpider):
    name = "storyder"

    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=("#movies", "#books"))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_item"),
    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = StoreItem()
    # some code for extracting the item's data
    return item
```

Still it can't detect new added categories (and there is not a clear pattern for using in `restrict_css` without fetching other garbage), but at least it's complying with the requisites of the client: 2 rules, one for extracting category's links and other for extracting item's data.

Answer (score 1):

the `CrawlSpider` rules don't work like you want, you'll need to implement the logic by yourself. when you specify `follow=True` you can't use callback, because the idea is to keep getting links (no items) while following the rules, check the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)

you could try with something like:

```
class StoreSpider (CrawlSpider):
    name = "storyder"

    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]
    # no rules
def parse(self, response): # this is parse_category
    category_le = LinkExtractor("something for categories")
    for a in category_le.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(a.url, callback=self.parse_category)
    item_le = LinkExtractor("something for items")
    for a in item_le.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(a.url, callback=self.parse_item)
def parse_category(self, response):
    category = StoreCategory()
    # some code for determining whether the current page is a category, or just another stuff 
    if is a category:
        category['name'] = name
        category['url'] = response.url
        yield category
    for req in self.parse(response):
        yield req
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = StoreItem()
    # some code for extracting the item's data
    return item
```

Comment: the output of `scrapy crawl storyder -o output.json -t json` is just the list of categories, and some other links, but there is no item at all. IMO, it's not entering in `parse_item` because checking the log, when it crawls a link of a item, it's returning name and url, which are the fields of StoreCategory.